# getting json data with d3.json() from php not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, d3.js

I am using Javascript d3.js library to draw some charts which are getting data from a MySQL database using php. I have used d3.json() to read from a php file which is 'echo'ing some JSON value. This works fine in my PC XAMPP server but not working on a 000webhost free server. Can someone please tell me what could be the problem? I am getting JSON data using The following way .

```
d3.json(d3/section1/section1.php, function(data) {...
```

the php file is echo ing the following json array:

```
[{"spark":[1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9],"mes":[88],"mark":[90],"info":"Network"},{"spark":[0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.5],"mes":[87],"mark":[85],"info":"ERP"},{"spark":[1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9],"mes":[90],"mark":[100],"info":"Data Warehouse"},{"spark":[1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9],"mes":[95],"mark":[90],"info":"Web Site"},{"spark":[1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9],"mes":[98],"mark":[88],"info":"Email"},{"spark":[1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9],"mes":[90],"mark":[96],"info":"HR"},{"spark":[1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.1,0.4,0.8,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.6,0.9],"mes":[100],"mark":[92],"info":"Problem Tracking"}]
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Any JS errors? Can you confirm the browser is making the call and if so, what is the response?

Comment: I am getting No JS errors. I don't know how to check response but I used alert before and after the call like alert("bbb"); d3.json(d3/section1/section1.php, function(data) { alert("aaa");.... and the first alert is apearing but the second one is not. That means the response is not coming.

Comment: Are you using any JS debugging tools like Firebug?  They show you JS errors in the console log and have a way to look at the response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The online server was a free server which is embedding a javascript enclosed by html tags at the end of each page. That was creating problem calling the expected correct JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the URL need to be a string?

```
d3.json("d3/section1/section1.php", function(data) {...
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by string? The same way from a json file it works both my pc and online. Like: d3.json("d3/section1/section1.json", function(data) {...

Comment: If you mean query string to send data by url, then no, it doesn't reqire. the php is not using any $_GET or $_POST variable. it's getting data from a perticular mysql table and making it echo as the above json format.

Comment: All I was pointing out was that in your example above, you did not have quotes around the file you are trying to access.  You need quotes around `d3/section1/section1.php`, which you don't have in your example.